# Initializing matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm using this Code to create a python matrix (5 rows, 2 columns) :

```
[[0 for x in xrange(2)] for x in xrange(5)]
```

Can some one explain that part `0 for x in xrange(2)` and why it didn't worked when i tried to do it as follows :

```
[[0 for x in xrange(2)] 0 for x in xrange(5)]
```

Comment: Because `[0 for x in xrange(2)] 0` is an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have here a nested list comprehension. The first bit

```
[0 for x in xrange(2)]
```

creates a list of length 2, with each entry set to 0. This list is set as value for the second list comprehension. The following would yield the same result:

```
zeros2 = [0 for x in xrange(2)]
# create 5 copies of zeros2
zeros2x5 = [zeros2[:] for x in xrange(5)]
```

Comment: Your last example does *not* yield the same result, since `zeros2x5` would contain five references to the *same* object, namely `zeros2`.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow Yes, your right! I wanted to illustrate the concept, and forgot about that.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your example.

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question is a nested list comprehension. In Python for example

```
[x*x for x in range(10)]
```

returns

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

That syntax means "collect the value of `x*x` where `x` is each elements contained in `range(10)`"

You can of course write also things like

```
[42 for x in range(10)]
```

that will give

```
[42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```

(this is exactly the same as above, simply the value `x` is not used in the expression that you want to collect)

That "list comprehension" is however an expression itself so it can be used in another outer list comprehension... for example

```
[[x*y for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
```

will return

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 6]]
```

In the special case of a numeric constant (or any other immutable) you can use a simpler form to build a matrix:

```
[[0] * 3 for x in range(4)]
```

that returns

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

because **multiplying** a list by an integer `n` you get a list composed of `n` copies of the original list concatenated (and so `[0]*5` returns `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`).

Note that however the apparently similar

```
[[0] * 3] * 4
```

doesn't do the same thing. The reason is that while still displayed as

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

in this case the outer list will be composed of 4 references to the same row, not 4 independent rows. This means that after the code

```
x = [[0] * 3] * 4
x[0][0] = 9
```

`x` contains

```
[[9, 0, 0],
 [9, 0, 0],
 [9, 0, 0],
 [9, 0, 0]]
```

and not

```
[[9, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

as it would happen with a real matrix composed of independent rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
[0 for x in xrange(2)]
```

means "Write a list with a "0" for every element in (0, 1)" so a list with 2 entries, both "0" will be created.
So you can see

```
[[0 for x in xrange(2)] for x in xrange(5)]
```

creates a list with 6 entries. Each entry will be the result of

```
[0 for x in xrange(2)]
```

At the end you have a list, containing 5 lists, containing 2 zeroes.

In your code, the second "0" made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ar = []
Ar.append([1,2,3,4])
Ar.append([2,5,6,7])
Ar.append([3,8,10,11])
Ar.append([4,9,12,13])
```

By creating list of list using list apprehension, I am able to index like

```
print Ar[2][2]
```

Output

```
10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
m=int(input("Enter row"))

n=int(input("Enter column"))

a=[] #Blank Matrix

for i in range(m):#Number of Row Input

    b=[]#Blank List

    for j in range(n):#Number of col Input

        j=int(input("Enter Number in Pocket ["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]")) #Show Row an col Number 

        b.append(j)#add Row Element

    a.append(b)#Add list In Matrix

print(a)#Print Matrix
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answers already present.